# How to retrieve data from .php file

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode

I have a .php file that queries a MySQL database and gets the value of a row. *(a set of names)* I want a tableview to be populated with these values in Xcode. (This is for iOS) ***How do i access the .php file from within my app?*** Any help is appreciated!

Comment: invoke the php script using a standard http request, its output would be your data. what form that data takes is up to you and your client-side viewing app. generally it's json or xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know anything about obj-c - you could create a url handler to communicate with your server. Then, after making the proper .h file you would call a function like this, which returns an NSArray from the json results from your php script:

```
-(NSArray *) getUrl: (NSString *)myRequestString: (NSString *)jsonKey{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myRequestString]];

    if (jsonData) {

        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);

            // Handle Error and return
            return;

        }

        NSArray *jsonItems = [jsonObjects objectForKey:jsonKey];
        if(jsonItems == nil || [jsonItems count] > 0)
        {
            return [jsonObjects objectForKey:jsonKey];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"not working");
    } 

    return [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

Where you pass the url you want to call as well as the expected json key from that result. You don't need the json key per say, but I use this to abstract the request for one reason or another. This is pretty much just an example so don't drop it in and expect it to work perfectly unless you can glance at the code and understand what each portion does.

Not a very good example, but the important part is this:

```
dataWithContentsOfURL
```

If you google search that with whatever version of ios you're targeting you should find at least half a dozen fully working examples.

I'm going to stop there before going through a massive tutorial since there are many upon many out there. If you have something more specific to ask just post a comment and I may update my answer.

Comment: Assuming that you knew something about objective-c, you wouldn't return a retained NSArray in a method, it would be autoreleased, or you would return nil. Furthermore, the request is synchronous and should be asynchronous and therefore run in the background or separate thread.

Comment: that's good to mention. I'm posting from an example that is in a project bin. I'll upvote if you provide a more useful example. BTW I say assuming you know anything about obj-c as in general file structure and calling methods. It's nothing like PHP so maybe the OP is just starting

Comment: @KaiQing I am a beginner with Objective-C but I'm a fast learner. Where would i put the URL to the php file?

Comment: Well, you COULD replace this: [NSURL URLWithString:myRequestString] with [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoururl.com"] but that would defeat the purpose of passing the url to the method. Instead of modifying this example, you should google search something like "dataWithContentsOfURL ios5" and find a full example done properly

Answer (score 1):

Can you access a url to see the data in your browser? That's step one.  Get that working first.  Once you've got that set, form that url in xcode.  If it's dynamic (there are parameters), make sure that the url is created appropriately. Then just make a call to fetch that url via an http request.  Make sure that the server (php) and your client (the app) are speaking in the same format, json, xml, plain string, etc.

Comment: Yes I can view the data in a browser. There aren't any parameters. Its just a row of data containing a few names. Can you give me an example of a fetch using a temporary url? like google.com/index.php Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: This is what I have so far.    `NSURL *storeDataUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.247.245.87/index.php"];
    NSData *storeNameData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:storeDataUrl];`